# .htaccess rewrite all 'other' URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hopefully this is a simple one. I have a really basic .htaccess that rewrites any request to `/admin` (or `/admin/etc`) to `/_admin/index.php`. So far so good:

```
#Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin

RewriteRule ^admin/$ /_admin/index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin$ /_admin/index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ /_admin/index.php [QSA]
```

What I also want is a generic "catch all else" rule that rewrites any *other* url (`/users`, `/turnips/`, `/some/other/path` and so forth) back to `/index.php`

I can't seem to get that to work - its either `server error 500`'s or `/admin` also gets rewritten to the root page. I'm sure I just need to do something with `RewriteCond` but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding this before each rewrite rule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php  [NC]`, to stop the error.

Comment: @faa That doesn't seem to change anything. Just to clarify - the .htaccess file I've listed there does work perfectly fine as it is. I just need to add an extra rule that will catch any other url that isn't `/admin`: so `/users` and anything else will all rewrite to `/index.php` in the site root (whilst `/admin/` remains pointing at `/_admin/index.php`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after the other rules. It would be the default rule if the previous rules are not applied.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .*        index.php        [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also match other files like images etc?

Comment: Yes, matches everything according to this: `...anything else...` in your comment. However, what do you want to be redirected to index.php in root directory?

Comment: I didn't ask the question, I just doubt he/she wants to do that

Comment: I see. Well, it seems that's what the OP wants according to his comment. But, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @faa kjetilh isn't me. Although they have a point; I wasn't clear enough about "anything". CSS, images, javascript - anything that isn't a php/html script shouldn't be redirected. I can figure it out from here though I think. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem so difficult with a condition like this one: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|css|png|whatever) [NC]` where the types are excluded from the rule.

Comment: Changing the last line to `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L,QSA]` seems to do what I want it to

Comment: The difference is the regex in your comment requires something in the URL path, while that one in my answer doesn't `*`. That's because I didn't know exactly what you wanted. Glad you found it, though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you add the **L** flag to your rewrites so you're sure to avoid unintended matches after matching a rewrite (unless intended of course).

Secondly WordPress uses the following code to rewrite all URLs that are not matching *index.php* OR a file that already exists. This way files accessed directly like images, text files, downloads etc are not rewritten. Note that originally it also included the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to also not rewrite directories but you seem to want that behaviour:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php - [L]
```

Please see if this fits your needs.